# Three gifs with same src, reload just one of them

Tags: html, jquery

So I have three images with one gif over them:

```
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
        <img id="cardAnimationOne" src="assets/images/iso.gif" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/online-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
        <img id="cardAnimationTwo" src="assets/images/iso.gif" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/gestion-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
         <img id="cardAnimationThree" src="assets/images/iso.gif" alt="">
         <img src="assets/images/integrar-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a function that reloads the gif if the mouse is on the image:

```
$('#cardAnimationOne').on('mouseenter', function(){     
  $('#cardAnimationOne').prop('src', '');
  $('#cardAnimationOne').prop('src', 'assets/images/iso.gif');
});
```

I want to reload/retrigger each one any time my mouse is on them (so there is one of these functions for each image, and for my testing/debugging purposes I'm enabling just the first one).
My problem is that with the JS above all three gifs get reloaded even though I'm just selecting the first one.

I came to a solution by saving the gif three times with different names. In this case the functions works as intended for each one of the images.

My question is:
Why do all the images get reloaded/triggered if they share the same `src` even if I'm only coding for one to reload?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Just FYI, when you post an answer the OP will be notified anyway, so there's no need to comment as well.

Comment: Sounds like when you replace it in browser cache the browser repaints all versions with the updated copy. You might be able to use a query string for each one so although image source is the same the urls are slightly different

Comment: @Clonkex my bad - i have misunderstood the question entirely. Sorry. I agree due to aysnc functionality in the browser no matter what happens the gifs will reload if they are all same name.  I have deleted my non addressed solution to this question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping All good, I realised there was a sensible way around the problem so I posted my own answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the URLs are the same, some browsers (or all?) will keep the GIFs in sync. I don't know if this is documented or specced behaviour.

The simplest way to make the GIFs move separately is to use a unique URLs for each GIF, as you discovered, but creating a copy of the file for each time you want it to appear might not be practical. Instead what you can do is add a URL parameter. This will make the URL appear unique to the browser, but it will have no effect on the GIF.

```
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
        <img id="cardAnimationOne" src="assets/images/iso.gif?whatevertextyouwant=1" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/online-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
        <img id="cardAnimationTwo" src="assets/images/iso.gif?whatevertextyouwant=2" alt="">
        <img src="assets/images/gestion-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards_item">
    <div class="cards_item-imgs">
         <img id="cardAnimationThree" src="assets/images/iso.gif?whatevertextyouwant=3" alt="">
         <img src="assets/images/integrar-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

In theory you could also do something like this:

```
let GifLoadingNumber = 0;

$('#cardAnimationOne').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('#cardAnimationOne').prop('src', 'assets/images/iso.gif?whatevertextyouwant=' + GifLoadingNumber);
  GifLoadingNumber++;
});
```

...but in my testing Chrome stopped loading it from cache after a few tries and started loading it from the server every time, which made it reset twice (once immediately when the mouse moved over it and the second time about a half-second later when the test GIF loaded from the server).

My [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqaxjdm0/).